# How to Degrade DevExpress from 12.2 to 11.2 Windows Form

Tags: .net, winforms, version-control, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

we have C#.net application using DevExpress 12.2 version and we have to degrade to 11.2, 
what is the best way to degrade ?

Comment: Just change the DLLs references to the previous versions and correct all build errors. What is your question?

Comment: I want to know any other way to do the work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the couple of simple steps for downgrading your project from 12.1 to 11.2:

1. Backup your project
2. Install DXperience 11.2
3. Run the [ProjectConverter tool](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#ProjectConverter/CustomDocument2529) to downgrade your project to DXperience 11.2.  The project converter will perform all the required changes in project files.